# Delete row from dataframe and reset index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to subtract some values from two different dataframes but they are different sizes. I am able to make them both the same shape using df.drop(). However, this does not reset the row index. Example code below.

```
df1

   Value
 0  1.5
 1  2
 2  1
 3  5
 4  3

 df2

    Value 
 0  2
 1  6
 2  5
 3  5
 4  6

 df1.drop(df1.index[0]
 df2.drop[df2.index[4]


 df1

     Value
 1   2
 2   1
 3   5
 4   3

 df2


     Value
 0   2
 1   6 
 2   5
 3   5

 df1['Value']-df2['Value'] 

 0   NaN
 1   -4
 2   -4
 3   0
 4   NaN
```

The values are being subtracted based on the index of the row, not on the actual position of the values. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If lenfth of both rows is same is possible subtract by numpy array for avoid align index values each other:

```
df1['Value']-df2['Value'].to_numpy()
#oldier pandas versions
#df1['Value']-df2['Value'].values
```

Or create same index in both `Series`:

```
df1['Value'].reset_index(drop=True)-df2['Value'].reset_index(drop=True)
```